# Show only two model properties in the item list with Django REST Framework

Tags: list, django-rest-framework

I want to show only two properties of the model in the list of items, but then in a specific item show all the properties

/api/character <-- show a list with name and id properties
/api/character/30 <-- show all properties of the item with id 30

Code i have in serializer.py:

```
class CharacterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    language = LanguageSerializer(read_only=True)
    region = RegionSerializer(read_only=True)
    realm = RealmSerializer(read_only=True)
    faction = FactionSerializer(read_only=True)
    race = RaceSerializer(read_only=True)
    wow_class = ClassSerializer(read_only=True)
    spec = SpecSerializer(read_only=True)
    talents = TalentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    pvp_talents = PvpTalentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    covenant = CovenantSerializer(read_only=True)
    soulbind = SoulbindSerializer(read_only=True)
    conduits = ConduitSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Character
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'language', 'region', 'realm', 'faction', 'race', 'wow_class', 'spec', 'talents', 'pvp_talents',
        'covenant', 'covenant_rank', 'soulbind', 'soulbind_abilities', 'conduits', 'item_level', 'media', 'avatar', 'rating_2v2',
        'rating_3v3', 'rating_rbg', 'max_2v2', 'max_3v3', 'max_rbg', 'achievement_points', 'account_achievements', 'seasons',
        'alters', 'date_added', 'last_search', 'checked']
```

code in views.py

```
class CharacterViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CharacterSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = Character.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
    search_fields = ['name']
    filterset_fields = ['language', 'region', 'realm', 'faction', 'race', 'wow_class', 'spec', 'covenant', 'soulbind']
```

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I have created two serializer for the model one for list and another for detail

```
class TalentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Talent
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class TalentDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    language = LanguageSerializer(read_only=True)
    wow_class = ClassSerializer(read_only=True)
    spec = SpecSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Talent
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'language', 'description', 'spell_id', 'talent_id', 'wow_class', 'spec', 'tier_index', 'column_index', 'level', 'icon']
```

in the viewset I have redefined the get of the class:

```
class TalentViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TalentSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = Talent.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
    search_fields = ['name']
    filterset_fields = ['language', 'spell_id', 'talent_id', 'wow_class', 'spec', 'tier_index', 'column_index', 'level']

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return TalentDetailSerializer
        return TalentSerializer
```

Now works well /api/talent return a list with id and name of items and /api/talent/id return the item with all props of model :)